# delete WSFC 2012 cluster role fails

Tags: sql-server-2012, windows-clustering

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> get-cluster

Name
----
sql2012poc_cl1


PS C:\Windows\system32> get-clustergroup

Name                                    OwnerNode                               State
----                                    ---------                               -----
AG1                                     srvgnpw049                              Failed
Available Storage                       srvgnpw049                              Offline
Cluster Group                           srvgnpw049                              Online


PS C:\Windows\system32> remove-clustergroup AG1
remove-clustergroup : The object has been deleted from the cluster.
At line:1 char:1
+ remove-clustergroup AG1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Remove-ClusterGroup], ClusterCmdletException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ClusterObjectNotFound,Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.RemoveClusterGroupCommand
PS C:\Windows\system32> get-clusterresource
get-clusterresource : The object has been deleted from the cluster.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-clusterresource
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-ClusterResource], ClusterCmdletException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ClusterObjectNotFound,Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.GetResourceCommand
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

I am trying to delete Cluster Role from Windows 2012 Failover Cluster but get above error in both WFC Manager GUI and PS. AG1 cluster role is still visible in GUI and Cluster Core Resources is empty in GUI.

Please advise how AG1 role can be removed and cluster core resources be visible again.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick workaround ended up deleting whole cluster:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Import-Module FailoverClusters
PS C:\Windows\system32> clear-clusternode
Clear-ClusterNode
Are you sure you want to forcefully clean up cluster node SRVGNPW049?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): Y
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

And then recreating a new one.